# Trying to use FlexibleAdapter for Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm trying to use the FlexibleAdapter lib for Android but I'm getting a blank view...maybe someone can help me.

I'm getting the base code from here : https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter/wiki/5.x-%7C-Setting-Up

I'm really a noob and it seems I'm missing something important.

When I run the app, I just get a blank MainActivity.

Thanks!

**MainActivity.java**

```
package win.network610.yannickg.flexibleadapter_sandbox;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import eu.davidea.flexibleadapter.FlexibleAdapter;
import eu.davidea.flexibleadapter.items.IFlexible;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Optional but strongly recommended: Compose the initial list
        List<IFlexible> myItems = getDatabaseList();

// Initialize the Adapter
        FlexibleAdapter<IFlexible> adapter = new FlexibleAdapter<>(myItems);

// Initialize the RecyclerView and attach the Adapter to it as usual
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public List<IFlexible> getDatabaseList() {
        List<IFlexible> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new MyItem("1", "Hello"));
        list.add(new MyItem("2", "World"));
        list.add(new MyItem("3", "World3"));
        list.add(new MyItem("4", "World4"));
        list.add(new MyItem("5", "World5"));
        list.add(new MyItem("6", "World6"));
        list.add(new MyItem("7", "World7"));
        return list;
    }
}
```

**MyItem.java**

```
package win.network610.yannickg.flexibleadapter_sandbox;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import eu.davidea.flexibleadapter.FlexibleAdapter;
import eu.davidea.flexibleadapter.items.AbstractFlexibleItem;
import eu.davidea.flexibleadapter.items.IFlexible;
import eu.davidea.viewholders.FlexibleViewHolder;

/**
 * Where AbstractFlexibleItem implements IFlexible!
 */
public class MyItem extends AbstractFlexibleItem<MyItem.MyViewHolder> {

    private String id;
    private String title;

    public MyItem(String id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    /**
     * When an item is equals to another?
     * Write your own concept of equals, mandatory to implement or use
     * default java implementation (return this == o;) if you don't have unique IDs!
     * This will be explained in the "Item interfaces" Wiki page.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object inObject) {
        if (inObject instanceof MyItem) {
            MyItem inItem = (MyItem) inObject;
            return this.id.equals(inItem.id);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * You should implement also this method if equals() is implemented.
     * This method, if implemented, has several implications that Adapter handles better:
     * - The Hash, increases performance in big list during Update & Filter operations.
     * - You might want to activate stable ids via Constructor for RV, if your id
     *   is unique (read more in the wiki page: "Setting Up Advanced") you will benefit
     *   of the animations also if notifyDataSetChanged() is invoked.
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }

    /**
     * For the item type we need an int value: the layoutResID is sufficient.
     */
    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.item_flexible;
    }

    /**
     * Delegates the creation of the ViewHolder to the user (AutoMap).
     * The infladed view is already provided as well as the Adapter.
     */
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder createViewHolder(View view, FlexibleAdapter<IFlexible> adapter) {
        return new MyViewHolder(view, adapter);
    }

    /**
     * The Adapter and the Payload are provided to perform and get more specific
     * information.
     */
    @Override
    public void bindViewHolder(FlexibleAdapter<IFlexible> adapter, MyViewHolder holder,
                               int position,
                               List<Object> payloads) {
        holder.mTitle.setText(title);
        // Title appears disabled if item is disabled
        holder.mTitle.setEnabled(isEnabled());
    }

    /**
     * The ViewHolder used by this item.
     * Extending from FlexibleViewHolder is recommended especially when you will use
     * more advanced features.
     */
    public class MyViewHolder extends FlexibleViewHolder {

        public TextView mTitle;

        public MyViewHolder(View view, FlexibleAdapter adapter) {
            super(view, adapter);
            mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**item_flexible.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a [LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager) for your recyclerView. Try:

```
// Initialize the RecyclerView and attach the Adapter to it as usual
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```